# template duplicate list items when server re starts

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

This code displays items from the MenuItems collection in my app, but during development when the server re-runs, the list gets a new list added to the old "duplicate entries".
I need one list only and not duplicates.

Why is that happening and how to fix it? Thanks

```
/////////////////////////////////////
//       client code
/////////////////////////////////////    
<template name="mainMenu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="list-group menuItems">
          {{#each menuItems}}
            <li data-template="{{menuItem}}" role="presentation">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item menuItem">
                <img src="/abc.png">
                {{menuItem}} <span class="badge">&#x3e;</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Template.mainMenu.onCreated(function () {
  var template = this;
  template.handler = template.subscribe('menuItems');
});

Template.mainMenu.helpers({
  menuItems: function () {
    return MenuItems.find();
  }
});

Template.mainMenu.onDestroyed(function () {
  var template = this;
  if (template.handler && template.handler.stop) template.handler.stop();
});

/////////////////////////////////////
//       server code
/////////////////////////////////////    
var items =
  [
    {menuItem: "task1", group: "ab"},
    {menuItem: "task2", group: "ab"},
    {menuItem: "task3", group: "b"},
    {menuItem: "task4", group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task5", group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task6", group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task7", group: "b"},
    {menuItem: "task8", group: "b"},
    {menuItem: "task9", group: "b"},
    {menuItem: "login", group: "ab"},
    {menuItem: "logout", group: "ab"}
  ]
_.each(items, function (doc) {
  MenuItems.insert(doc);
})
```

Comment: you do not need to manually unsubscribe from `onDestroyed`. Just try it without this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_.each(items, function (doc) {
  MenuItems.insert(doc);
})
```

This fragment of code inserts the new bunch of data each server start, so as result your collection grows with each run. You can easily check it if you look at your collection (`meteor shell` or `meteor mongo` can help). Wrap it in this construction

```
if (!MenuItems.find().count()) {
    _.each(items, function (doc) {
        MenuItems.insert(doc);
    })
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I don't have any more upvotes left for today, I will vote it up tomorrow. :). One more thing is to include `items` declaration in the `if` condition as well. :)

Comment: Yes, of course you can include "items" inside, but it's more about readability of code. You can put it in a function and call it like `initFill` (just an example)

Comment: Yes, readability is one thing and performance another important thing. Though it doesn't make difference in this scenario, it stills adds an unnecessary overhead of creating `items` array when `!MenuItems.find().count()` is `false` as well. :)

Comment: @Kishor, I agree, it's a micro-optimisation for that small case, but if we need to fill big collection and it's a generation process then it's a good practice to hide it inside for performance

Comment: On problem with this solution, some times the MenuItems collection has items which need to be replaced with another items, This is not allowed with this fix.

Comment: @FredJ. in this case change insert to upsert